# Find two occurences in the same line

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I have the output of a command, something like this:

```
machine: alias_machine: status Idle - true -
machine2: alias2: status Idle - true    -
machine3: alias3: status Idle - false    -
machine4: alias4: status Charging - False    -
```

I have to search if, in one of those machines, the status is Idle and False (at the same time).

To do that, I use this:

```
if output.find("Idle") and output.find("false"):
    print ("Blablah")
```

But the problem is, that "Idle" and "false" could be found in other lines, so this does not do the trick.

I also tried this, and it works:

```
if output.find("Idle - false"):
    print ("Blablah")
```

But there is a problem, if there is an update in the software or something and the output changes (whitespaces, breaklines, tab, etc), I would have to rewrite the code again...

If I transform it into a list, the format is going to be changed... So I could not use the result later...

Comment: If the lines themselves are not consistent, are you guaranteed that each "input part" start with a pattern `machine\d*`?

Comment: If things change in some unknowable way, how can you be expected to accommodate it?

Comment: Under what condition will whitespaces or tabs be added? For example, would you ever end up with `I  dle` or `f\nalse` (false separated by a newline)?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, all those machines starts with the same name.

Comment: @OneCricketeer There is no condition, it could change if the software updates and it changes the format (it happened some times).

Comment: The "best" you could do is find each `machine\d*:` with regex. But if you have no control over any other keywords, then the next best approach is scanning letter-by-letter for your conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to match `Idle` followed by `false` on the same line:

```
import re

if output.search(r'Idle.*false'):
    print("blahblah")
```

By default `.` will not match newlines, so this will match both words on the same line, regardless of what's between them.